# ACF repeaater Not working even after coding the fields right

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

My code

```
<?php if( have_rows('mir_global_header') ): ?>
<div id="mid-bg1">
    <div id="top-container1">
        <?php while( have_rows('mir_global_header') ): the_row();
                        $count = get_row_index();
                        $header_image = get_sub_field('header_image');
                        $header_image_text = get_sub_field('header_image_text');
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $header_image; ?>" id="<?php echo $count; ?>" alt="<?php echo $header_image_text; ?>" />
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

[image]

I've done everything as mentioned in the documentation. It's not working. Is it because ACF pro is not activated? Is there any other way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is not working? What is your desired outcome and where do you expect it to work?  Currently, your question is quite vague.

Comment: I just want to display the images from a loop. But It doesn't work

Comment: You want to display images from loop of what ? Options page or Post type ? have_rows by default is geting current post ID .

Comment: From the options page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ACF options page.  You have to specify that in the `have_rows`. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/

```
<?php if( have_rows('mir_global_header', 'option') ): ?>
    <div id="mid-bg1">
        <div id="top-container1">
            <?php while( have_rows('mir_global_header', 'option') ): the_row();
                $count = get_row_index();
                $header_image = get_sub_field('header_image');
                $header_image_text = get_sub_field('header_image_text');
                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $header_image; ?>" id="<?php echo $count; ?>" alt="<?php echo $header_image_text; ?>" />
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your fields in an options page or a classic post_type?

Test this for print a result

```
$mir_global_header = get_field('mir_global_header');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($mir_global_header );
echo '</pre>';die();
```

PS : ACF Gallery gives the same result ;)
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/

Comment: it's not printing anything, I've sent the screenshot of the data I've saved too. Please take a look